# Struts2 CRUD, how to update the model : ModelDriven. It's always blank in the JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2, crud, model-driven

I'm not able to retreive my Model in my JSP to update the object.

```
public class ViewDashboardAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven {
private Clinique clinique = null;

@Override
    public Clinique getModel() {
        return clinique;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        clinique = service.read(1);

        // at this point my object is populated

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

in my JSP I want to have something that simple

```
<s:textfield name="nom" key="clinique.nom" value="nom"></s:textfield>
```

but my textfield is always blank.

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private Clinique clinique = new Clinique();

@Override
    public Object getModel() {
        return clinique;
    }


public void setClinique(Clinique clinique ){
   this.clinique =clinique ;
}

public Clinique getClinique(){
   return clinique ;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I though.  ModelDriven will be useful for validation, but not for the front end.

Comment: Model Driven Interceptor will put your domian object on the top of value stack when request processing cycle is going on,